# Are recurring invoices and other items available via the Quickbooks Online API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm looking to automate the creation of invoices and the quantities for line items.  I would like to have an invoices for a customer act as a template for the next time the invoice is created so that the line items and their corresponding prices are kept for that company, but the quantity for the item would be changed by the API.

Recurring templates seem like the best solution for this to create a template for that company's invoice, but I don't see a way to query for existing recurring items.  Is this possible via the Quickbooks Online API?

Answer (score 2):

The supported entities are listed on Intuit's website right here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

If it's not on the list, it's not supported.

Unfortunately, recurring templates are not on the list, which means they are not supported.

With that said... recurring templates are the wrong way to approach this - that's an incredibly over-complicated and error prone way to do this since you'd have to generate them and then query for what was generated and then modify it.

Why don't you just use the API to actually create the invoices? That should be super simple to do...

Better yet, if your task is to do basically metered/usage-based billing, why not use a [QuickBooks integrated recurring billing platform to do the work for you?](http://chargeover.com/)